# Using an open drain buffer as a logic level step down converter

Tags: uart, buffer, logic-level, step-down, open-drain

I'm trying to convert a 3V3 UART to 1V8 UART with an open drain buffer, but the output of the buffer is always high.

See the schematic below for the circuit. On the input to the buffer, there is a 0V - 3V3 UART, working exactly as it should. On the output, I'd expect a 0v to 1V8 UART. But I'm getting a 1V8 always high.

It's not a dead chip, as the same problem persists over multiple PCBs (10) - there are no shorts, the resistance values are correct and the supply rails are stable. For testing the output of the buffer is not connected to the downstream device.

What is going on?

[image: Schematic of buffer in question]

The markings on the chip:

[image: The markings on the open-drain buffer]

Comment: What markings are on the chip?

Comment: Is it possible that the chip is mounted 180-degrees off? Which package are you using?

Comment: Using DRY package - chip marking is "HL" - as far as I can tell (it is tiny), the chip is correctly mounted

Comment: Is it possible that you got counterfeit chips? Desolder one of them, put them on a breadboard adapter, and just test them to see if they work at all.

Comment: The board seems awfully sparse of GND plane stitch holes. That pour on the top layer is largely useless by itself. There should be a via right next to each GND terminal - both chip pins and capacitor pads. Take a differential wideband probe and measure voltage between C304.GND and U301.GND. It may be that there's lots of offset/noise.

Comment: What happens if  you connect a resistor from the output to GND of maybe 100 ohms?

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I'm leaning towards it being counterfeit chips - I'm confident the ICs work because they are doing so in similar logic level shiting roles in other parts of the PCB. But just not in this step-down configuration

Comment: RE Layout: There is a sparsity of stitching vias in this part of the PCB because there is a four-lane CSI bus on the bottom layer of the PCB. (6-layer PCB) I decided that a 9600 baud UART buffer was less critical than the CSI bus. That's why there is some weird stuff happening with the supply vias as well. I don't have access to a dif probe, but I'll have a sniff around with the scope on the grounds anyway

Comment: @skipper_the_penguin That reasoning makes sense. Thank you for clarification. It seems like you did everything right.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a divider, no logic needed:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdqeIb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming C_LOAD=50pF load capacitance due to trace parasitic capacitance, and input capacitance of the MCU, the circuit mostly retains the rise- and fall-times of the source signal. Realistically, the 1.8V output will swing 10%-90% in less than 50ns. C1 can be tweaked and likely lowered to limit overshoot. In many circuits, C_LOAD will be effectively lower, and thus C1 will be proportionally lower as well.

L1 models C1's series inductance.

On the pre-production board, C_LOAD should be measured at 100kHz or 1MHz, with R1 and R2 removed, and then C1 chosen to equal about 6/5*C_LOAD.

As shown the input and output signal waveforms are:

[image: 3.3V and 1.8V UART waveforms]

If you also need step-up conversion from 1.8V to 3.3V, that can be done too without ICs - in that case, you'd need to clarify in the question.

Comment: Yeah, this works when there is a known and controlled source impedance - but the devices that plug into the input of this buffer are varied. In other places on the PCB, I use dividers where there is controlled impedance -  in this case, I can't - hence the buffer.

Comment: @skipper_the_penguin Makes sense. At a cost of an extra resistor and a capacitor, one can just go with dividers everywhere and use a push-pull buffer (non open-drain).